# Fatal error: Call to undefined function

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function date_add() in
>   /home/....../public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-ads/admin/edit-ad-update.php
>   on line 70

The line have the folowing code:

```
date_add($ad_data["real_end_date"], new DateInterval("P".$ad_plan->days_length."D"));
```

Can some one help me?

Answer (score 5):

`date_add` is available since php 5.3 . Check your php version. You can do that by using ... the [`phpversion()`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.phpversion.php) function, if it is available for your version of php, of course ;)